# Neo4j In Query with dynamic array

Tags: neo4j

```
var arr = ["a","b","c","d"];
await session.run(`MATCH (x:Test WHERE x.name IN ${arr}`)
```

I use the neo4j database in nodeJs and I am writing queries but I am taking errors for arr, I tried many methods but I took `arr` not defined.

Comment: The query is a string, maybe you can try something like: 'MATCH (x:Test WHERE x.name IN ' + arr.    something similar is working form me with py

Comment: i tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is not formatting the string the way you would expect:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
let x = `MATCH (x:Test) WHRE x.name IN ${arr}`
console.log(x)
```

This prints:

```
"MATCH (x:Test) WHRE x.name IN a,b,c,d"
```

Which is not valid Cypher.

To overcome this issue, just let the Neo4j driver do the formatting for you by adding a parameter to your query:

```
await session.run(
    "MATCH (x:Test WHERE x.name IN $arr",
    {arr: arr},
)
```

Check reference for this syntax [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#consuming-records-with-promise-api).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var arr = ["a","b","c","d"];
await session.run(`MATCH (x:Test WHERE x.name IN ${JSON.stringify(arr)} `)
```